# Problem with presence.status and nickname Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { bold, italic, strikethrough, underscore, spoiler, quote, blockQuote, inlineCode, codeBlock } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Option, User, Options, UserContextMenuInteraction } = require(`discord.js`)

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()

        .setName('userinfo')
        .setDescription('Use this command to see information about you')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('Select a user').setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {
        // ${interaction.client.uptime}
        var userStatus = '';

        const userResult = interaction.options.getUser('target');
        const memberResult = interaction.options.getMember('target');
        const joinedDate = new Date(memberResult.joinedTimestamp).toLocaleDateString();
        const createdDate = new Date(userResult.createdTimestamp).toLocaleDateString();

        if(memberResult.presence.status == 'offline') {
            userStatus = 'Offline';
        }
        if(memberResult.presence.status == 'idle') {
            userStatus = 'Idle';
        }
        if(memberResult.presence.status == 'dnd') {
            userStatus = 'Do Not Disturb';
        }
        if(memberResult.presence.status == 'online') {
            userStatus = 'Online';
        }

        let days = Math.floor(userResult.client.uptime / 86400000);
        let hours = Math.floor(userResult.client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
        let minutes = Math.floor(userResult.client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
        let seconds = Math.floor(userResult.client.uptime / 1000) % 60;

        const exampleEmbed = {
            color: 0x0099ff,
            title: `Information of ${userResult.tag}`,
            description: `${interaction.user.username} has used the command ` + inlineCode(`/${interaction.commandName}`),
            fields: [
                {
                    name: underscore('Nickname:'),
                    value: `${memberResult.nickname}`,
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: underscore('ID:'),
                    value: `${memberResult.id}`,
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: underscore('Uptime:'),
                    value: `${days}d, ${hours}h, ${minutes}m, ${seconds}s`,
                    inline: false,
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: underscore('Status:'),
                    value: `${userStatus}`,
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: '___Created at: ___',
                    value: `${createdDate}`,
                    inline: false,
                },
                {
                    name: '___Joined at: ___',
                    value: `${joinedDate}`,
                    inline: false,
                },
            ],
            footer: {
                text: `im so sorry about of bug on [uptime] and [status]. Soon will be fixed :)`,
            }
        };
        
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed], ephemeral: false });
    },
};
```

I'm trying to get `...presence.status`  and `.nickname` of members, but it's giving an error on console if the status of the member is offline.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\commands\userinfo.js:24:28)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\index.js:32:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:74:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\.Folder Rizky\test vscode\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

Is this a problem with `Intents`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem with your code is the privileged intents. To fix this issue, you must turn on `Presence intent` in the discord developer portal.


[image: PRESENCE INTENT (Turn this one on) If your bot tracks presence data, you may need the presence intent to receive presence event data. NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more sewers, this will require Verification and whitelisting. Read more here. \n SERVER MEMBERS INTENT If your bot tracks server members or downloads the entire member list, you may need the server members intent to receive member events and the member list. NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more sewers, this will require Verification and whitelisting. Read more here.]


After that, in your code add `GUILD_PRESENCES` to your client intents array like so:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });
```

Comment: it all was my do it, and it's not change something :(